# In Matlab: How to keep all xTicks but xTicklabels just on every 6 xTicks?

Tags: matlab, plot, axis-labels

I have created a graph with data from an Excel file. I need to keep all the xticks but the xticklabels to appear just on every 6 ticks. I have tried doing this:

```
tickStep=6;
Sheet=2;
filename='MyData.xlsx';
[~,xAxis]=xlsread(filename,Sheet,'A2:A60'); 
yAxis=xlsread(filename,Sheet,'B2:B60'); 
plot(1:numel(xAxis),yAxis) 
set(gca,'xtick',1:numel(xAxis)) 
set(gca,'xticklabel',xAxis(1:tickStep:numel(xAxis)))
```

Unfortunately it does not work as all the xticks are plotted, but the xticklabels appear upon each xtick instead of every 6th like I was trying to achieve. I have spent quite a long time thinking about the solution:-(. I need help. Thanks.

edit: I've included an image to help answer questions below:
[image]

In relation to this post, would it also be possible that the xticks appear every 4 xticks instead of keeping all of them, at the same time that the xticklabels are plotted every 6 xticks?, not sure about this.

Comment: Note that the matter of alignment is now also addressed in the answer.

Comment: With regard to your last question, you can only place labels where there are already ticks, so your ticks marks have to appear anywhere you need a label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still need to enter an empty string (or empty cell) for the ticks that will have no label. You can do this by replacing the last line with these three lines:

```
xTickLabels = cell(1,numel(xAxis));  % Empty cell array the same length as xAxis
xTickLabels(1:tickStep:numel(xAxis)) = xAxis(1:tickStep:numel(xAxis));
                                     % Fills in only the values you want
set(gca,'XTickLabel',xTickLabels);   % Update the tick labels
```

---

*Edit in response to questions below...*

The reason your labels appear to be offset from the ticks is because the bottom of the letters appears to be getting lined up with the tick mark. I'm guessing you want the text justified such that the center of each letter lines up with the tick mark. There's no way to do this with the standard MATLAB axes, but there are some submissions on [the MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange) that convert the tick labels to [text objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) and thus give you more options for customizing the [text properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html):

- [XTICKLABEL_ROTATE](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3486-xticklabelrotate) by [Brian Katz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/8955)
- [Format Tick Labels](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15986-format-tick-labels) by [Alexander Hayes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/29071)

Once you convert the labels to text objects, you can then adjust the rotation or vertical justification by modifying the [`'Rotation'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html#Rotation) and [`'VerticalAlignment'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html#VerticalAlignment) properties, respectively.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering. I have tried the code but I cannot make it work:-(. All the xticks are kept but I still get a xticklabel on each xtick, moreover, my xticklabels are replaced by numbers now (from 1 to 60)...

Comment: @gnovice. I have just realised that the xticklabels are plotted in between the xtick marks and not on the xtick marks. Why does this happen?, Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @Sarah: I'm not sure why it would do that. It plotted them on the ticks in the tests I did. What exactly is in `xAxis`?

Comment: @gnovice: I have string data on the x-axis. It might be due to the rotation of my xticklabels?. Is there any function in Matlab that allows positioning labels on the tick marks as it is possible in Excel?. I include here an example of the x-axis of my graph (done for every 2 ticksteps). The x labels are not exactly on the tick marks and when I plot large amount of data in can be a little bit confusing.

Comment: @gnovice: I have updated my post, I have another question in relation to this post.